# How can i start and stop the Simulation in Anylogic with commands?

Tags: simulation, anylogic, modeling

When I simulate my model, the simulation should not start until the button has been clicked. The simulation should stop when the number of Unit (variable) is reached.
Which commands can I use to control the simulation and where exactly do I have to enter them?

Answer (score 0):

You can pause your model calling `pauseSimulation()` at any point. And continue using `run()`.

The location to enter those commands depends on your model setup. Either try yourself or add some more details (in a [new issue](https://benjamin-schumann.squarespace.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow))

See more commands [here](https://anylogic.help/anylogic/running/controlling-model-execution.html#controlling-the-model-execution-from-code).